# bean of type that could not be found

Tags: spring

Can anyone tell me how to structure my packages to resolve this issue.
[image: Is something wrong with my package structure]

[image: All classes]

Answer (score 0):

Have you annotated your Employee class with **@Enitity** annotation ?

Example

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int empID;
}
```